# Stream a movie to a friend

Tags: video, ubuntu, media-player, streaming

I want to stream a video file I have locally to show it to a friend, e.g., to watch a movie together.

Is there such a program?

I use Ubuntu but I don't know what OS my friend uses.

Comment: Do you have a budget? Is your friend on the same Internet connection as you?

Comment: Find out what OS your friend uses and update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes.

---

#### VLC

I have noticed that the popular, alternative media player: ***VLC***, appears to provide options for this. If the menu is hidden, you should be able to access it with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

---

#### Python

Other than that; you can implement your very own, custom, client/server model with ***Python 2.7/3.x*** ((`python2.7`)/(`python3.5`)) and these modules:

- ***OpenCV*** (`cv2`).
- ***Flask*** (`flask`).

Apparently it's a popular approach among CCTV / security-camera systems.

Check out these references:

- [www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example)
- [blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Answer (score 1):

You could [set up a Plex Server](http://www.howtogeek.com/252261/how-to-set-up-plex-and-watch-your-movies-on-any-device/) and then allow him access to it but it's going to be difficult as I guess you have a dynamic IP.